# Which library should I use for random dates in c++

Tags: c++, date, random

I want to generate a random date in `C++` to send a birthday message in that day.
I was wondering if we have any libraries in `C++` that provides random date considering the leap years?

Thanks,

Comment: You can generate a random unix timestamp (`time_t`) in the range of your choice and use it as a date.

Comment: Does it work in Windows as well?

Comment: It's part of the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime)

Comment: `std::chrono` might be nice too

Comment: http://ideone.com/zvM0jD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulling my comment here, since nobody answers:

You can generate a random unix timestamp (`time_t`) in the range of your choice and use it as a date.

Comment: `time_t` isn't neccessarily in seconds or even milliseconds.

Comment: @Simple, what's important is that it's an arithmetic type.